# How to open a file path from csv using python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to be able to open a file path in the csv cell using python. Currently, I am able to read the csv using python but I am unsure of how to open the file path and retrieve the information I want from the file using python. I am unsure of how to proceed after reading the csv to proceed to read the file path and go to the file in the file path. Then I want to retrieve some data from the file and put it in another csv. I want to do this for all the rows with content in the csv file. I have attached my current code below. Please advise on how to proceed.

`

```
     with open(r'\\excel.csv', newline='') as dh:
     for row in csv.DictReader(dh, strict=True):
       with open(r'\\excel.csv', 'r') as df:
       data = df.read()
       #read the file path and go to the file in the file path and retrieve data in it and put the retrieved data into a csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the first `csv` file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df_csv1 = pd.read_csv(r'\\excel.csv')
```

Then, simply loop through the field containing the `path` names, load with pandas, perform your computations and then save as `csv` into a new path:

```
for file_path in df_csv1['paths']:
    df_csv2 = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    ...
    # perform your computation
    df_new = func(df_csv2)
    ...
    df_new.to_csv('new/file/path.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. What do I do if there are no headers in the csv above?

Comment: @programmingnoob pd.read_csv comes with different parameters: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html . But to load without header, you can set it to None: `pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)`